# Implementing FilterText or Search input to a reactjs app

Tags: reactjs

Currently, this code display records from via **reactjs.** Now I have added search/filter text to allow me search data by users 
**name, Age and gender**. To this effect, I have set the search state and has also initialized **handleChange function** for the search text
but does not know how to connect it to **json** records to enable me search records by name, Age and gender. Can someone help me with that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>    
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 this.state = {value: ''};
this.state = {searchdata: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "tom", Age: "89" , gender: "female"}
      ],

    };

  }


 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>
          <h3>Search/Filter Records by name, Age and gender</h3>

<input type="text" placeholder="Search by name, Age and gender"  id="searchdata" name="searchdata" type="text" value={this.state.searchdata} onChange={this.handleChange} />




          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 

              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

**An Updated section.**

This updates is based on the solution of **Mr. Hamzal H.**
If I implement the filterRecord function  as per code below

```html
filterRecord = (record)=> (record.name.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.gender.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1)
```

it will throw error shown in the screenshot below
[image]

If Implement FilterRecord function as per below

```html
filterRecord(record) {record.name.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.gender.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1
}
```

It will show error

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.filter ()
    at Application.render (eval at transform.run (browser.min.js:4),**

**Below is the full implementation but cannot get it to work**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 this.state = {value: ''};
 this.state = {searchdata: ''};


    this.filterRecord = this.filterRecord.bind(this);
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87" , gender: "female"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19" , gender: "male"},
        { name: "tom", Age: "89" , gender: "female"}
      ],

    };

  }


 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
filterRecord = (record)=> (record.name.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.gender.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1)
/*
filterRecord(record) {record.name.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.gender.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1
}
*/

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>
          <h3>Search/Filter Records by name, Age and gender</h3>

<input type="text" placeholder="Search by name, Age and gender"  id="searchdata" name="searchdata" type="text" value={this.state.searchdata} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<ul>
{
     this.state.rec.filter(this.filterRecords).map((obj, i) => 
          (
            <li key={i}>
              {obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 

             </li>
          )
      )
}

 </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter the rec array to show only elements that match the search text:

The filter function may look like this:

```
filterRecords = (record)=> (record.name.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.gender.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1)
```

And then use the filter function before mapping to show only elements that match

```
{
     this.state.rec.filter(this.filterRecords).map((obj, i) => 
          (
            <li key={i}>
              {obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender} 

             </li>
          )
      )
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Hamzal, I have tried implementing your solution but it shows error of unexpected token. I have tried some other way round based on your solution but still cannot get it work. I have updated my post to reflect various ways I tried to implement your solution but it still throw errors. Please Sir can you see the Updated section of my post to see the errors it displays and how I tried to implement  your solution. Please can you help me further. between thanks for your efforts so far

Comment: The problem was with the filter function name in the invocation... here is a sandbox code of the solution working as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/2v0xp0n34j.